# Get parent div text having a specific class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link on click of that i want to get the parent div text having a specific class.How can we do this in jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="rcmp_li lft">
    <div class="rcm">
        <div class="cmplogowrap clr cmp">
            <a class="reclogo lft" href="#"></a>
            <a class="lft cmp" href="#">
                <div class="tpjobwrap">
                    <div class="compName font_15">ABC </div>
                    <div class="tpjob_desc">Construction</div>
                    <div class="tpjob_desc">Mumbai</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="lnk cmpjobs" href="#"> Active </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cmpfollow_wrap clr">
        <div class="followbtnwrap rgt">
            <a onclick="abc(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
        </div>
        <div id="my_follow61" class="followcnt rgt">6 </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On Click of `abc()` i want to get the value of diva having class `compName`

i Have tried this

```
$(obj).parents('div[class^="compName"]').html()
```

But this is not working

Comment: `compName` is not parent of clicked element. Its child of `rcm` which is sibling of clicked elements parent

Comment: okk so what i have to do for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target element. you need to use:

```
$(obj).closest('.rcmp_li').find('.compName').html()
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9gct75b/)**

Comment: @RayonDabre: yes if class is going to remain static.

Answer (score 1):

Try including `:has()` selector at parameter passed to `.parents()` to return `div` element having child element `.compName`

```js
function abc(obj) {
  console.log($(obj).parents(":has(.compName)").find(".compName").html())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="rcmp_li lft">
<div class="rcm">
    <div class="cmplogowrap clr cmp">
<a class="reclogo lft" href="#"></a>
<a class="lft cmp" href="#">
<div class="tpjobwrap">
    <div class="compName font_15">ABC </div>
    <div class="tpjob_desc">Construction</div>
    <div class="tpjob_desc">Mumbai</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<a class="lnk cmpjobs" href="#"> Active </a>
</div>
<div class="cmpfollow_wrap clr">
<div class="followbtnwrap rgt">
<a onclick="abc(this)" href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a>
</div>
<div id="my_follow61" class="followcnt rgt">6 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work because its parent is not the div you are looking for.

```
$(obj).parents('div[class^="compName"]').html();
```

Also you cannot use "parents" And to travel to parent hierarchy you will have to use parent().parent() where you need to know the exact parent level.

Here you can simply use `$("div.compName").html();`